# Removing heading numbers from docx

Tags: python, pandoc, python-docx

I need to use python to pre-process docx (Word) documents, so that pandoc can properly convert them into markdown. One of the key requirements is that the styles of the docx document should be "cleaned up", in particular that the numbering of *headings* (Heading 1, Heading 2, etc.) should be removed.

**Restrictions:** I know how to do that using VBA (and likely could do it from python using PyWin32 or such). But it is a requirement that it must be implemented without Microsoft Windows and without LibreOffice/UNO.

How can I use the python-docx package to do that? I have looked at the documentation and there does not seem to be any proper to do it (actually the [heading numbering style](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/style.html#numberingstyle-objects) does not seem to be implemented). Did I miss something?

Unless I should use another method, such as applying a different Word template to the docx document, with the main styles correctly predefined according to my requirements? Could that be done through an available python package?

**Code in VBA**
This is the code in VBA that got the job done:

```
Sub RemoveHeaderNos()
' Remove the header nos

    Debug.Print "Removing header numbers and formatting..."
   For Each s In ActiveDocument.Styles
        s.LinkToListTemplate ListTemplate:=Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

On terminology, I'm understanding you to mean "the numbering of heading paragraphs" as opposed to something like page numbers in the page headers, have I got that right? The two terms "heading" and "header" are unfortunately close and mean quite different things, in Word parlance anyway :)

I'm assuming your paragraph headings are numbered, like 'Heading 1' style causes the next sequential integer to be prefixed to the heading paragraph text, like '9. Ninth section heading', (then likewise for Heading 2 -> 9.1, 9.2, etc.

You're correct that this hasn't been implemented in python-docx yet. You would need to get as close to the XML element in question (perhaps the `<w:style>` element for Heading 1 for example) as possible using the python-docx API, and then use lxml calls to manipulate the XML under that.

You'd need to start with a strategy for what XML changes you need to make. `opc-diag` is handy for that. You can change the .docx manually (preferably a radically stripped-down, super-short document) using Word to make it look the way you want, then compare the XML before and after to discover what changes you need to make to the XML.

Then you can validate your strategy by extracting a .docx (using opc-diag), manually updating the XML with the minimum required changes, repackage it (also using opc-diag), and load it in Word to make sure it behaves as expected.

I suspect there's a way to "disconnect" the "Heading 1" style from a numbering definition in the styles.xml part that would accomplish what you're after and be a fairly straightforward handful of element changes.

Anyway, that's where I would start.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, this is definitely the numbering of heading paragraphs (styles). Perhaps we could get a simpler solution if we deleted **all attributes** of the "Heading 1", "Heading 2", etc. styles? Could that be done?

Comment: In other words, keep only the bare-metal defaults of the styles?

Comment: That sounds a bit radical, but it makes me think that if you deleted the existing Heading 1 style and created a new one with the same name, it wouldn't have the numbering. It's worth a try.

Comment: For the purpose, it might work? (see the VBA example above). I will look it up.

Comment: That looks very promising; it indicates that there's just the single linkage to the list definition. If you print out the XML of the Heading 1 style I can probably pick out the right element for you. You would do something like this: `print(document.styles['Heading 1']._element.xml)`

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved in [version 1.17 of pandoc](http://pandoc.org/releases.html#pandoc-1.17-20-mar-2016), released on 20 March 2016 ("Don’t turn numbered headers into lists"). If other people meet the same issue, the best thing at this stage would be to upgrade to a that version or a later one.

Nevertheless, the exploration of the various solutions with the python-docx was interesting, because it indicated a point of possible improvement.